# can anyone explain the steps of creating a server in androidstudio using java

Tags: android

In detailed steps of creating a server of a particular address in androidstudio using java

iam new to androidstudio expecting a valid and clear explanatoin from folks

Comment: Regarding creating a server, I will assume you mean to make a back-end application that your app can hit. Java offers several flavors of this. I will pick one randomly and say: look at Tomcat (https://crunchify.com/how-to-start-stop-apache-tomcat-server-via-command-line-setup-as-windows-service/). That link will likely get you started on the journey. Do you aim to run a server on an Android device?

I made many assumptions and could be misunderstanding your question without more context from you.
 
Localhost usually comes as a first step if you aim to run a server.

Comment: yes i want to create a server on android device for that i want to develop an app in androidstudio, is it even possible???

Comment: What kind of server? And what should it serve?

Comment: Server that has an ipaddress and a port number i.e client serve based one

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.